# How do I call NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue in Swift?

Tags: swift, nslocalizedstring

[`NSLocalizedString` in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocalizedstring) has a simple function in Swift:
[`NSLocalizedString(_: comment:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1418095-nslocalizedstring), but where is the Swift equivalent of [Objective-C's `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocalizedstringwithdefaultvalue)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSLocalizedString(_: comment:)` isn't the Swift function at all, it's actually [`NSLocalizedString(_:tableName:bundle:value:comment:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1418095-nslocalizedstring). `tableName`, `bundle`, and `value` all have `default`s, which is why they don't need to be specified in the common cases. Thus, Swift has just one function to handle all cases of the various Objective-C localization macros.

```
func NSLocalizedString(_ key: String, 
                       tableName: String? = default, 
                       bundle: Bundle = default, 
                       value: String = default, 
                       comment: String) -> String
```